# T4 runtime template path specification

Tags: c#, templates, runtime, t4

I have a quite a bit of T4 runtime templates in my solution and I'd like to organize them in folders, but my builds fail as soon as I do so. The failures are simply because of template can't be found. 
How can import or add a search path for t4 runtime template in my classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify either absolute paths or relative paths. If the included file resides within the same solution, use relative paths. Example:

> <#@ include file="..\..\..\..\EPS\EPS.Framework\EPS.Framework.Common\Localization\ML.ttinclude" #>

Here the included file resides withing another project in the same solution. Use `..\` to move up one folder.

Comment: This is if I wanted to include a template within a template, right ?

Comment: This is if I wanted to include a template within a template, right ? What about when referencing a template name in the code and it isn't in the same folder ?

Comment: See [Run-Time Text Generation with T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx).